# Why GWT app didn't fire when users click on the href link that have the domain that is the same as host domain?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am using GWTP

Here is the problem

I have a customer page like this `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#!cust;custID=1`

Suppose I have this code:

```
InlineHTML myLink=new InlineHTML("<a href=\"http://car.com" > car </a> ");
```

When clicking on `car` link it went to car page.

Ok, now I have other `InlineHTML`

```
InlineHTML myLink=new InlineHTML("<a href=\"http://127.0.0.1:8888
/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#!cust;custID=2\" > cust2 </a> ");
```

When clicking on `cust2`, the url changed from `#!cust;custID=1` to `#!cust;custID=2` & just stayed there, it did not refresh the whole page or fire the page as It did in the "car" link example.

I have not deployed my app with a real domain yet, but I think GWT app will not fire when users click on the href link that have the domain that is the same as host domain.

How to fix this simple issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue to fix. You provided exactly the same URL in both links:

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

Everything after the hash (`#`) sign [indicates a document fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), i.e. position within a page.

Comment: …or rather, navigation within the GWTP application here; so it should trigger the GWTP events for place changing.

Comment: I can't use GWTP Place Manager cos the url <a href> is provided by user.

Comment: It can still trigger a place change. The idea behind Activities and Places is that a place can be bookmarked, emailed, typed in a browser window, etc.